# Basic Traefik configuration issue

Tags: traefik

To start with, I wanted to implement the basic traefic configuration as described on the Traefic Get Started page. Below is my compose and toml file. When I scale the whomami service, I see as many frontends ... with no loadbalancing. Any idea what is wrongly configured? Many thanks - Christian

Docker Compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik # The official Traefik docker image
    command: --api --docker # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
      - "9090:8080" # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /home/traefik:/etc/traefik # Where the Traefik configuration is

  whoami:
    image: containous/whoami
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:whoami.docker.localhost"
```

Traefik.toml

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"

[frontends]
  rule = "Host:whoami.docker.localhost"

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "docker.localhost"
swarmMode = true
exposedByDefault = false
```

Update: 
I saw on other threads that, with Swarm node, it the traefik port needs to be configured as well. Below is therefore the command and the compose file that I'm using for the deployment of the stack on a swarm manager node (trial platform where the manager and workers node are on the same). However, that does not modify the end result, i.e. the service is not visible by Traefik:

`docker stack deploy -c docker-compose-traefik-stack.yml  traefik_stack`

```
    version: '3'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik # The official Traefik docker image
    command: --api --docker # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
      - "9090:8080" # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /Users/obech01/Runtime/traefik:/etc/traefik # Where the Traefik configuration is

  whoami:
    image: containous/whoami
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:whoami.docker.localhost"
        - "traefik.backend=whoami"
        - "traefik.port=8000"
```

Comment: Hi Christian, how are you determining that no load balancing is taking place? Are you loading the service via browser and examining the `hostname` that is returned?

Comment: Indeed, this is what I'm observing, i.e. it is always the same hostname that is returned.

Comment: I progressed a bit and noticed the following: if I add the labels to the service, they are not taken into account by Traefik and the service does not show up in the dashboard. On the other end, if I add the lables as "container labels" in the service, then I have as many frontends as I have containers when I scale. Bottom line seems to be that the issue is with the service lables and how they are taken into account by Traefik.

Comment: Are you using the `docker-compose` command to up the amount of servers? It'd be good to know definitively if the individual containers of the scaled up service each have the proper labels.

Comment: I'm actually deploying the service on a Swarm (hence the swarm=true in the toml file). Indeed, the labels are defined at the containers level. When you remove the labels from the containers and put them as "service labels", they are not detected by Traefik. So since the label are at the container level, this is why (I believe) you have as many frontend as containers ... which is not the desired result I think.

Comment: For information,below is the command and the compose file that I'm using for the deployment of the stack on a swarm manager node (trial platform where the manager and workers node are on the same).:

Comment: add the label
traefik.docker.network, with either the default network associated to your containers or another on that both should use (better).
For now you should keep it simple until it works with basic container and compose default mode.